# Pandas plotting two columns with series defined by value in third column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

Hi I have a pandas dataframe that looks like

```
deflector  wFlow  aContent  DO Difference
64         3  127.5        10       2.007395
65         3  127.5         3       1.163951
66         3  127.5         5       1.451337
67         3  127.5         7       1.535639
68         3   24.0        10       1.046328
69         3   24.0         3       0.854763
70         3   24.0         5       0.766780
71         3   24.0         7       0.905270
72         3   56.0        10       1.274954
73         3   56.0         3       1.298657
74         3   56.0         5       1.049621
75         3   56.0         7       1.004255
76         3   88.0        10       1.194174
77         3   88.0         3       1.056968
78         3   88.0         5       1.066173
79         3   88.0         7       1.097231
```

I would like to plot the aContent column vs the DO Difference column with each line defined by the wFlow column (x = aContent, y = DO Difference, 4 different lines, one for each wFlow.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation. Minimal, complete, verifiable example applies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem. StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service. Also, add what you tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas-dataframe-pivot) the data and use [`pandas.dataframe.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas-dataframe-plot):

```
df.pivot(index='aContent',columns='wFlow',values='DO Difference').plot()
```

[image]